# In R, how can I reduce the number of rows in a data frame based on an interval?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
Gene <- c("gene 1", "gene 2", "gene 3")
Number <- c(2,1,0)
df <- data.frame(Gene,Number)
df
  Gene Number
1 gene 1      2
2 gene 2      1
3 gene 3      0
```

Then I want to only include rows which contain values between 0.5 and 1.5:

```
df$Number[(df$Number >= 0.5) & (df$Number <= 1.5)]
[1] 1
```

This isolates values in between 0.5 and 1.5 but gives a numeric output. I need the output to be a data frame like this:

```
Gene     Number
gene 2     1
```

This will allow me to identify which genes have values in between 0.5 and 1.5

Comment: use `df[(df$Number >= 0.5) & (df$Number <= 1.5),]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `(df$Number >= 0.5) & (df$Number <= 1.5)`  operates on a single vector named `Number` in your case and returns again a vector with 3 elements `c(F, T, F)` . So when you subset your vector Number on the basis of these results only 2nd element of that vector is returned.

Instead use results to subset df on the basis of rows.  Thus, filter full data, instead of filtering just one column, like this-

```
df[(df$Number >= 0.5) & (df$Number <= 1.5),]

    Gene Number
2 gene 2      1
```

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr you can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(between(Number, 0.5, 1.5))
    Gene Number
1 gene 2      1
```